# Sql Datatype needed for FCK editor Text storing

Tags: sql, fckeditor

I just want to save long text through FCK Editor in Sql Database. I've given the datatype as 'text' but it is not accepting more than 500 characters. I just need the datatype where I can save atleast 10000 characters. What will be the perfect alternative for this solution.

Please Answer me. 
Thanks.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? Firebird?

Answer (score 0):

Did u try longtext or varchar(max)

Refer to this 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp